# mysqli prepared statement in login form doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to secure my login form using mysqli prepared statement.

I am using the following code and I'm keep getting the wrong information entered error!

here is my code:

```
   if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        $manager =  $_POST["email"]; 
        $password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);
        $stores = $_POST["stores"];

            // Connect to the MySQL database
            include "config/connect.php";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "SELECT  email, password, storeShop
     FROM storename
     WHERE email = ?
       AND password = ?
       AND storeShop = ?"
);
        $manager =  $_POST["email"]; 
        $password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);
        $stores = $_POST["stores"];
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $manager, $password, $stores);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);//<-- CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF!
    //update was successful
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
}


$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
         }
         $_SESSION["storeShop"] = $storeShop;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
         header("location: dashboard");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo "wrong information entered";
        exit();
    }
}
```

**but when I use this code, it works fine:**

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM storename WHERE email='$manager' AND password='$password' AND storeShop='$stores'";


$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

could someone please tell me what I am doing  wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT, This still doesn't work.

```
    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        $manager =  $_POST["email"]; 
        $password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);
        $stores = $_POST["stores"];

            // Connect to the MySQL database
            include "config/connect.php";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "SELECT  email, password, storeShop
     FROM members
     WHERE email = ?
       AND password = ?
       AND storeShop = ?"
);
        $manager =  $_POST["email"]; 
        $password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);
        $stores = $_POST["stores"];
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $manager, $password, $stores);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
{
        $existCount = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
         }
         $_SESSION["storeShop"] = $storeShop;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
         header("location: dashboard");
          mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
         exit();
    } else {
        header("Location: data");
        exit();
    }
   //<-- CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF!
    //update was successful
}


}
```

SECOND EDIT:

```
    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        $manager =  $_POST["email"]; 
        $password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);
        $stores = $_POST["stores"];

            // Connect to the MySQL database
            include "config/connect.php";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "SELECT  email, password, storeShop
     FROM members
     WHERE email = ?
       AND password = ?
       AND storeShop = ?"
);
        $manager =  $_POST["email"]; 
        $password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);
        $stores = $_POST["stores"];
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $manager, $password, $stores);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
{
        $existCount = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
        if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
{
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
         $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
     }
     $_SESSION["storeShop"] = $storeShop;
     $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
     $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
     $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
     header("location: dashboard");
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
     exit();

} else {
    header("Location: data");
    exit();
}
    }
   //<-- CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF!
    //update was successful
}
}
```

Comment: `$query` does not exist

Comment: P.S. I feel like prepared statement code is very ugly and all over the place. maybe that's why its harder for the hackers to crack it as it is all over the place so they simply give up!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT  email, password, storeShop
     FROM storename
     WHERE email = ?
       AND password = ?
       AND storeShop = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $manager, $password, $stores);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($manager, $password, $stores);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

              {      
         $_SESSION["storeShop"] = $storeShop;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
         header("location: dashboard");
               exit();
               }

        }
        else {
        header("Location: data");
        exit();
        }
        $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to update this;

```
$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

to

```
$existCount = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```

Refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php#example-1759) for further details

**Edit:**

And in your code it should be ;

```
if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
{
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
         $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
     }
     $_SESSION["storeShop"] = $storeShop;
     $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
     $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
     $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
     header("location: dashboard");
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
     exit();

} else {
    header("Location: data");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: isn't it also because close is before? Once closed the data shouldn't be available?

Comment: You will use it right after `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` . And remove second `$existCount =....`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. still does the same thing.

Comment: Have you used it right after `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` ?

Comment: Your code still wrong. See my updated answer for the right one

Comment: No, unfortunately still the same. please view my second Edit.

Comment: But your second edit is not mine. Could you please use my full code?

Comment: I have though! after `if ($existCount == 1) {` I have used your code. am i missing something?

Comment: that code doesn't work I'm afraid. it opens a page with `not found 404` in it. and the URL looks strange which is `mysite.com/directory/__DIR__..mysite.com`

Comment: and one more thing, your code allows anyone to login to the system without even entering any login details! can you please do me a favour and delete your answer so I can delete this question please?